# При нажатии на ListView вызвать меню

Tags: java, android

Имеется `ListView`, в котором находится информация. Как сделать так, чтобы при долгом нажатии на элемент списка появлялось контекстное меню, в котором были бы пункты удалить/изменить.

Comment: распишите вопрос шире. а то заминусуют и закроют ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам должен подойти ContextMenu. Это контектное меню со списком действий, которое вызывается при долгом тапе.
Как его использовать с ListView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
-------
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);

registerForContextMenu(lv1);
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

Далее переопределяете эти 2 метода:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
        .getMenuInfo();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.edit:
    //действия при изменении
    return true;
case R.id.delete:
    //при удалении
    return true;
default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

"R.menu.context_menu" создаётся в отдельном файле.